# Listen for keyboard shortcut ESC + ESC then run some code

Tags: python, keyboard-shortcuts, pynput

I want to listen for the keyboard shortcut `ESC + ESC` and then run some code. What I mean is that, if the user presses the `ESC` key twice, then some code should get executed.

I tried the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
from pynput import keyboard

pressed = set()

def run(s):
    if (s == "switch"):
        print("Hello World!")

def on_press(key):
    pressed.add(key)
    print(pressed)
    if (pressed == 27):
        print("Hello World!")

def on_release(key):
    if key in pressed:
        pressed.remove(key)

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Please help me using the library that best serves my purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import time

from pynput import keyboard


class DoubleEscapeListener:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pressed = set()
        self.last_esc_time = 0
        self.double_press_threshold = 0.5  # Time within which two ESC keys must be pressed.

    def run(self):
        print("Hello World!")

    def on_press(self, key):
        if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
            current_time = time.time()
            if current_time - self.last_esc_time < self.double_press_threshold:
                self.run()
            self.last_esc_time = current_time

    def on_release(self, key):
        if key in self.pressed:
            self.pressed.remove(key)

    def listen(self):
        with keyboard.Listener(on_press=self.on_press, on_release=self.on_release) as listener:
            listener.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    listener = DoubleEscapeListener()
    listener.listen()
```

This code will run the `run` method when the `ESC` key is pressed twice within the `double_press_threshold` time. You can adjust this threshold according to your needs.